# Can parameter use as method body to make it re-usable in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkinsfile which ask parameter before triggering the build. But I want user to check and confirm the passed parameter. If parameters are passed correctly, then move further otherwise ask to choose parameter again.

```
//method getParameter() will be used to prompt parameter from the user

def getParameter ()  {
    parameters {
        string(defaultValue: "API", description: 'What application?', name: 'Application')
        choice(choices: ['DEV', 'UAT'], description: 'choose the environment', name: 'Environment')
    }
}



pipeline {
    agent any
    getParameter () // This line will call the parameter method first time 
    stages { 
        stage("primary"){
            steps {
                script {
                    sh '''#!/bin/bash +x
                    # here user will check and confirm the passed parameter are passed correctly
                    echo Application: $Application 
                    echo Environment: $Environment
                    '''
                    try {
                        input message: 'Please check the parameters along with their values', ok: 'Confirm'
                        } 
                    catch(err) {
                        getParameter () // This line will call if user do not passed the parameter correctly
                    }
                }
            }    
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Allowed only once, inside the pipeline block.

src: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters

So you can't define it in a stage. I think you're trying to replicated the `input` directive behavior (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#input)

I think you'd like to have something like this:

```
def getParameter()  {
    timeout(time: 120, unit: 'SECONDS') {
        script {
            // Show the select input modal
            def INPUT_PARAMS = input message: 'Please provide parameters', ok: 'Next',
                parameters: [choice(
                    name: 'ENVIRONMENT', choices: ['dev','qa'].join('\n'), 
                    description: 'Please select the Environment'
                )]
            env.ENVIRONMENT = INPUT_PARAMS.ENVIRONMENT
        }
    }
}
```